# Method 'Apply" of Object 'Sort' failed when sorting table with data

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code which is used to format multiple tables on multiple sheets. Right now it gives the error mentioned in the title when trying to sort a table with no data. Otherwise, it works just fine.

```
Dim sht as worksheet
Dim Tbl as Listobject

For Each Sht In Worksheets
If Sht.Name <> "Original" Then
    Set Tbl = Sht.ListObjects(1)
    

    
    With Tbl
    .ListColumns("Pass/fail").Range.Cut
    Tbl.Range(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Insert shift:=xlToRight
    End With
    
    With Tbl
    .ListColumns("Persons for corrective actions").Range.Cut
    Tbl.Range(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, -1).Insert shift:=xlToRight
    End With
    
    With Tbl
    .ListColumns("Created By").Range.Cut
    Tbl.Range(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, -11).Insert shift:=xlToRight
    End With
    
    With Tbl
    .ListColumns("Description of findings").Range.Cut
    Tbl.Range(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, -10).Insert shift:=xlToRight
    End With
    
    With Sht
    .Range("C:F").EntireColumn.Delete
    .Range("G:H").EntireColumn.Delete
    .Range("K:K").EntireColumn.Delete
    End With
    
    With Tbl.Sort.SortFields
            .Clear
            .Add Key:=Tbl.ListColumns("Planned closing date for action").DataBodyRange, _
                 SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                 Order:=xlAscending, _
                 DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    End With
    With Tbl.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

Tbl.DataBodyRange.AutoFilter field:=Tbl.ListColumns("Pass/fail").Index, Criteria1:="FAIL"

Sheets.Add After:=Sht

End If
Next Sht
```

When debugged it highlights this part:

```
   With Tbl.Sort.SortFields
        .Clear
        .Add Key:=Tbl.ListColumns("Planned closing date for action").DataBodyRange, _
             SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
             Order:=xlAscending, _
             DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```

So my question is, how to make this work when there is no data on a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the table contains any rows. The number of rows can be retrieved with property `.ListRows.Count`.

```
if Tbl.ListRows.Count > 0 Then
    With Tbl.Sort.SortFields
        .Clear
        .Add Key:=Tbl.ListColumns("Planned closing date for action").DataBodyRange, _
             SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
             Order:=xlAscending, _
             DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    End With
    With Tbl.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
       .Apply
    End With
End If
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!